# Windows console command: find a pattern inside a text?

Tags: windows-xp

I remember windows getting a command to search a pattern inside a text. Does there anyone know that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even before then, there's the FIND command (goes all the way back to DOS 2.0).

```
FIND "string" filename
```

The string needs to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for FINDSTR. It's available in Windows XP and later. Type

```
findstr /?
```

For usage info.